# Design Patterns or Good ways to solve the problem

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need to develop an application in Winform C# and trying to find out suitable design pattern for this application.

Basically, My application Interacts with couple of Exes and output is monitored and based on the output, user will click button to trigger another console application (as shown in fig).

Right now, I have written separate class for every console application with which my application is interacting. [image: Winform Application]

What are best ways to solve this problem (using Design Patterns).

Thank you,
Harsha

Comment: Do all of the console applications have anything in common?

Comment: The question's background is unclear, title is uninformative too.

Comment: what are the commonalities? What are the variabilities?

Comment: All console application are DICOM Exes and common thing is, all are executed in the same way with some argument list. Basically This is a Image Retrieving application build around DICOM Exes(StoreSCP, MoveSCU, FindSCU etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Are the Console App from 3d? 
If not, You are able to create another Project(DLL) with the methods of that apps, and use it on your Winforms app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All Console apps are from 3rd party